# How to open a new tab from chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome extension. I have tried the first sample exercise for creating extension. Now I am trying to open an URL in a new tab from the extension popup. 
Just I have added a HTML anchor tag in the popup.html page.

```
a href="www.google.com">Click</a>
```

But its not opening. It is trying to open the URL with following url within the popup itself.

*chrome-extension://ljamgfaclheagbikmcagffcbdbcoodna/www.google.com*

My popup.html has this code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style>
    </style>
    <!-- JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files for security. -->
     </head>
  <body>
  <b>Karthick</b>
  <a href="www.google.com">Click</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

And My Manifest.json have the following JSON

```
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "The first extension for my test",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

I dont have written anything in popup.js
I searched for it how to do it. But they said that I have to use the following.

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected({}, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: 'http://google.com'});
});
```

But I don't know the proper way/where to do it. Please tell me the steps to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

here is the solution, just add the following code to popup.js:

```
$(function() {
  $('#s').click(function() {
     chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://www.google.com'});
  });
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded');
```

and update your anchor tag to look something like this:

```
<a id="s" href="www.google.com">Click</a>
```

since we are using jquery selectors update your popup.html to:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <b>Karthick</b>
  <a href="www.google.com">Click</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

and to allow jquery in popup.html update your manifest to look something like:

```
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "The first extension for my test",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],  //<<--- do not miss this ","
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

If this does not work, lemme send you the crx of this.
Cheers!

Comment: I will check and let you know

Answer (score 3):

[Easy.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9863145/3345375) Put this in popup.html:

`<a href='google.com' target='_newtab'>Click</a>`

Or put this in the JS file:

`window.open('http://google.com','_newtab');`

Comment: You could also try using "_blank" instead of "_newtab".

Comment: Or jQuery. [It's really great and does all things.](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Hk1mt-RKYLc/UOkxShm6NrI/AAAAAAAACqo/LVmqHOfWV7g/s1600/20091116-so-large.gif)

Answer (score 2):

You may add a onclick-listener for the link.

```
var link = document.getElementById("link");
link.addEventListener("click", function(){
  chrome.tabs.getSelected({}, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: 'http://google.com'});
  });
}, false);
```

However i would use the `chrome.tabs.create()` function.

Comment: Its not working... Any permission related things... anything i wan to include which i have missed...

Comment: Have you added a class or id tag to the element matching this in the JavaScript code? e.g. `<a id='link'>Open</a>`